# How to i pass a dynamic variable in an API URL in Artillery.io

Tags: yaml, load-testing, artillery

I need to run a load test on artillery.io - the api will basically contain a query string as follows:

> https://<<thisishowtheurllookslie/username?id=AXXXX1

Basically,

```
https://<<thisishowtheurllookslike/username?id=AXXXX1 is the record for user AXXXX1
https://<<thisishowtheurllookslike/username?id=AXXXX2 is the record for user AXXXX2
https://<<thisishowtheurllookslike/username?id=AXXXX3 is the record for user AXXXX3
https://<<thisishowtheurllookslike/username?id=AXXXXN is the record for user AXXXXN
```

I need to run a load test with N number of users - my belief is i need to create a CSV file starting with AXXX1 to AXXXN rows .

How to I configure all this in the yml file?

So far my config looks like this:

```
config:
  target: https://<<thisishowtheurllookslike/username?id=AXXXX1
  phases:
    - duration: 60
      arrivalRate: 1
    - duration: 300
      arrivalRate: 10
```

I am unable to understand how to make username as dynamic in the the URL

Answer (score 1):

You should set your base URL in the target, and then set the path in the scenario using [variable substitutions](https://www.artillery.io/docs/reference/test-script#variables---inline-variables), with variables you can set in the Config.

```yaml
scenarios:
  - flow:
      - get:
          url: "/username?id={{ myVariable }}"
```

(you can also use querystring instead of setting them in the URL)

You can also load the variable from the csv using the same mechanism and the payload functionality: https://www.artillery.io/docs/reference/test-script#payload---loading-data-from-csv-files

Comment: Thank you for the response, i was able to run a quick test using the "variable substitution " using the following:

config:
  target: https://test.test-api.net/
  phases:
    - duration: 5
      arrivalRate: 1
  variables:
     userid:
      - "TEST2000002_CST01-X-002"
      - "TEST2000003_CST01-X-002"
      - "TEST2000004_CST01-X-002"
      - "TEST2000005_CST01-X-002"
      - "TEST2000006_CST01-X-002"
scenarios:
  - flow:
      - get:
          url: "/username?id={{ userid }}"

However, i am not able to run the same using the csv payload mechanism

Comment: My code using the payload csv method is as follows:
config:
  target: https://test.test-api.net/
  phases:
    - duration: 5
      arrivalRate: 1
  Payload:
    path: "userid.csv"
    fields:
        - "userid"

scenarios:
  - flow:
      - get:
          url: "/username?id={{ userid }}"

Comment: My csv file is as follows:

userid
TEST2000001_CST01-X-00
TEST2000002_CST01-X-00
TEST2000003_CST01-X-00
TEST2000004_CST01-X-00
TEST2000005_CST01-X-00

Comment: Hey @SatyaLochun! Glad that the variable substitution is working. 

CSV should work as well. It's hard to tell from your replies without proper code formatting (indentation), but I did spot two things: _1. the CSV doesn't need the first row with the header of `userid`, as you have already specified that in the fields section of the config; 2. In the config, `payload` key should be with lowercase, not capital;_

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hey it works - the issue was with the payload being in uppercase - the "P" was in capital. THANK YOU